# Is there a way to find redundant code and variables in a Dart program?

Tags: dart

I read somewhere that dart2js removes redundant code and variables. Is there a way in dart other than dart2js to test for redundant code and variables in a Dart program?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about tree-shaking?

If that's the case, see [this](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/01/minification-is-not-enough-you-need.html):

> Run the main application through the dart2js tool, which supports tree-shaking for both JavaScript and Dart outputs. Note there is no command-line option for tree shaking, because dart2js is always tree shaking. For simplicity's sake, let's generate Dart.
>
> dart2js --output-type=dart embiggen.dart --categories=Server

**Updated answer based on comments:** dart2js is meant to be used as part of the build process. It can do tree-shaking as well as other tasks, but it cannot be used as an aid in the development process, i.e. it can't be used to refactor your code. As far as I know there's no such tool available yet.

Comment: Does that only work with browser-based apps? I did try it but it didn't appear to work for command-line apps (ie. 'dart:io').

Comment: That should work for command-line apps as well. Reading again your question, what do you mean by "redundant"? AFAIK tree-shaking only removes unreachable code (sometimes included in the definition of redundant code), other kind of optimizations are made at VM level but I honestly don't know what it does to, e.g., duplicated code.

Comment: Please try with command-line apps and let me know if it works. By redundant I mean code that is not executed.

Comment: Just tried with the example from Seth's blog and it works, but I had to add --categories=Server to the arguments to make it work (won't find dart:io if I don't - going to update my answer). Could you post a sample of code where this doesn't work?

Comment: Ok, I'll try that and post a reply soon.

Comment: When you say "it works", what exactly do you mean? Now, I must admit to knowing nothing about dart2js apart from a little that I have read. However, looking at the output from it, it appears to create obfuscated code (possibly as a side-effect), so I cannot read it. Therefore, I cannot see how it can help me. Please correct me if I am wrong, or perhaps I can format the output. If you think that the results I am getting should be different, I'll post more information. Alternatively if there is a way to format the code, please advise.

Comment: Yep, the code is also modified - not sure if it can be called obfuscated since you just need to put newlines in it, but it may actually refactor your code (sort of). You can also minify the code by passing the --minify parameter.

But...it's all fine, unless you are looking for a way to clean your codebase. Is that what you are looking for? I may have missed the point. dart2js is made to be part of a "build" process, not part of the development process.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for something as part of the development process to analyze the code.

Comment: Ok, then AFAIK there's no such thing.